Cluster stability measurement for fuzzy clustering
I'm a biologist working in the data science field. I've successfully done clustering for a heterogenic disease with K-means. But I shifted to Fanny to get membership value and to be able to handle the boundaries. For k-means clustering, I used clusterboot (from fpc package) and bootstrapping to find the cluster stability. Given that the clusterboot is not compatible with fuzzy clustering, which approach do you suggest for assessing the cluster stability with fuzzy?
Thanks
